# How to find NSNotification object type?

Tags: macos, nstextview, nsnotifications

I am using NSNotification for my textView but this delegate method is also called for my textField click. So, how can i find out the object type of NSNotification???

Currently i am using:

```
MyTextView *text = (MyTextView *)[aNotification object];
```

here MyTextView is a class to refer textView. So, how can i differentiate the object type of NSNotification.

Please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend doing this. Create two separate methods for each action/notification with different names clearly stating what they are handling.

Anyway, what you're asking for is done like this

```
if ([[aNotification object] isKindOfClass:[MyTextView class]])
{ treat it like MyTextView }
```

I'm not sure what you mean with textField click, but it seems you may also need this

```
if ([aNotification isKindOfClass:[NSNotification class]])
{...}
```

Comment: I just used your suggestion and created a check for the class MyTextView and it worked. Thankx...

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5, as you can see from the following image,

`noti.object` is the type of `Any?`

find the type is to cast the `noti.object` to the type you want.

[image: 000]

Here is an example of RxSwift,

```
let observable = NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification( .login )
                   .takeUntil(self.rx.deallocated)
            .flatMap { (noti: Notification) -> Observable<Bool> in
                if let result = noti.object as? A{
                    // ...
                    return self.login(result.id)
                }
                else{
                    return Observable.of(false)
                }

            }
```